# Add x-values to numpy array containing only y-values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset that only contains y-values in one column. I want to insert a column of x-values that needs to be 0, 10, 20, 30... as long as the array.

how would I go about that?

Comment: Please provide an example of your expected result.

Comment: Please provided a detailed description of your initial step and your desired output.

Comment: Welcome, please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question on SO

Comment: Is this `pandas` or `numpy`?  Your terminology is a bit confusing.  If numpy it matters whether `y` is `(n,)` or `(n,1)` shaped.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
myY = [1, 4, 3, 6, 8, 4]
myX = [i * 10 for i,y in enumerate(myY)]

print(myX)  # -> [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

**Edit**

In case you are working with Numpy you could do something like the following:

```
myY = np.array([1, 4, 3, 6, 8, 4])
myData = np.vstack((myY, [i * 10 for i,y in enumerate(myY)]))
```

When

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your y is like

y:

```
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

You could do

```py
x = np.arrange(0, y.shape[0]*10, 10)
```

followed by

```py
x = x.reshape(-1,1)
```

x:

```
array([[ 0],
       [10],
       [20],
       [30],
       [40]])
```

Now stack them using

```py
np.hstack((x,y))
```

Result:

```
array([[ 0,  0],
       [10,  1],
       [20,  2],
       [30,  3],
       [40,  4]])
```